# Building jdk11 from openjdk's source code on Windows using Cygwin

Tags: openjdk-11

I am building jdk11 from openjdk source code.

**Details of env :**

- Platform : windows using Cygwin64
- Git repo : https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u.git

1. while running build it checks all dependencies are fine.
2. then prints Configuration summary:
3. then prints Tools summary
4. then prints below error

```
Build performance summary:
 * Cores to use:   2
 * Memory limit:   4094 MB
 
 
- C:/work/82caeaee125c418c/src/openjdk-jdk11u/make/Main.gmk:46: /cygdrive/c/work/82caeaee125c418c/src/openjdk-jdk11u/make/common/FindTests.gmk: No such file or directory
- gmake[1]: *** No rule to make target '/cygdrive/c/work/82caeaee125c418c/src/openjdk-jdk11u/make/common/FindTests.gmk'.  Stop.
- gmake: *** No rule to make target 'images'.  Stop.
- Process exited with code 2
- Process exited with code 2 (Step: build (Command Line))
- Step build (Command Line) failed
```

> In error file, it shows, FindTests.gmk is not there in system. But if I check its present on that path.

I don't know what's causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After little research, I found that, `gmake images` (On my machine, it was pointing to Perl repo's gmake, something like perl/bin/gmake) causing the problem on Cygwin.

Instead of that I used `make images` (pointing to /usr/bin/make) and it is working fine for me.

Please note, make is systems default make.
gmake is specifically GNU make. Sometime both refer same path. So be cautious while dealing with them.